# jQuery Mobile Loader Widget shows no animation when loaded from Google's CDN

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-cdn

jQuery Mobile's [Loader Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/) uses by default the [ajax-loader.gif](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/images/ajax-loader.gif) spinner, which on Google's CDN comes as a [46x46 blank image](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/images/ajax-loader.gif). This results in no animation being displayed ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3T3Tg/))

```js
 $.mobile.loading("show");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<p>Google CDN "jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"</p>
```

... when loading jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css from Google's CDN. (Compare to [jQuery's CDN](http://jsfiddle.net/g5A5b/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    <p> jQuery CDN "jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" </p>
```

or [Microsoft's CDN](http://jsfiddle.net/42VP5/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    <p> Microsoft CDN "jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" </p>
```

)

If this is in fact a bug at Google's CDN, how can it be reported? Google Hosted Libraries [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#troubleshooting) refers you to the discussion group, where I found [one question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-AJAX-Search-API/w48kUaGTBIw) (and [another at the jQuery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-googleapis-missing-ajax-loader-gif)) and no answers.

Comment: For any issue related to JQM, report it here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues good catch btw.

Comment: Reported it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7284), thanks. Thank you also @mark-bertenshaw for fixing the links.